# how to execute ros commands from php

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to run a robot through a web page, running nodes or halting them. It's possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274507/how-to-execute-ros-commands-from-php/) by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is quite possible. See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite)

---

Originally posted by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) with karma: 22 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0